# Перевести в Timestamp даты в виде "сегодня, 14:41" и "вчера, 14:41"

Tags: java, timestamp, simpledateformat

У меня задача распарсить форум и хранить данные в DB.

Для того что-бы перевести даты на пример `11 май 17, 19:45` я использую

```
final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm");
new Timestamp(simpleDateFormat.parse("11 май 17, 19:45").getTime());
```

Но свежие посты в этом форуме отмечены как `"сегодня, 14:41"` и `"вчера, 14:41"`.

Как мне поправить эту проблему?

`new SimpleDateFormat("как пределить что сегодня и вчера что-то значат?");`

Или возможно тут нужен какой-то другой способ?

Comment: Тут нет другого способа кроме хардкода `вчера` и  `сегодня`, проверки того, что дата на эту строку начинается и замены этой даты на вручную сформированную дату, основанную на времени девайса. Да, это может быть не точно и гарантии не даст, но иначе - никак.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот сделал такой костыль, если у кого-то будут идеи как сделать это лучше, буду благодарен если поделитесь.

```
public class TimeConverter {

    final private SimpleDateFormat format;

    TimeConverter() {
        this.format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm");
    }


    Timestamp convert(final String data) throws ParseException {

        if (data.contains("сегодня")) return this.todayConverter(data);

        if (data.contains("вчера")) return this.yesterdayConverter(data);


        return new Timestamp(this.format.parse(data).getTime());
    }

    private Timestamp todayConverter(final String data) {

        final String[] time = getTime(data);

        Calendar current = new GregorianCalendar();

        current.set(
                current.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                current.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                parseInt(time[0]),
                parseInt(time[1]));


        return new Timestamp(current.getTimeInMillis());
    }

    private Timestamp yesterdayConverter(final String time) {
        return new Timestamp(todayConverter(time).getTime() - 86_400_000L);
    }

    private String[] getTime(final String time) {
        final String[] arr = time.split(" ");
        return arr[1].split(":");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        TimeConverter tc = new TimeConverter();
        final Timestamp today = tc.convert("сегодня, 14:41");
        final Timestamp yesterday = tc.convert("вчера, 14:41");
        System.out.println(today);
        System.out.println(yesterday);
    }
}
```